# How to show button while hover over box using react?

Tags: reactjs, hover, mouseevent

I am working on a project, it is an online shop in react.
I would like to make "Quick view" and "Add to cart" buttons visible only while hovering over the product box they're in. Also, they should be clickable. Code of the ProductBox below`

```js
const ProductBox = ({ name, price, promo, stars }) => (
  <div className={styles.root}>
    <div className={styles.photo}>
      {promo && <div className={styles.sale}>{promo}</div>}
      <div className={styles.buttons}>
        <Button variant='small'>Quick View</Button>
        <Button variant='small'>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShoppingBasket}></FontAwesomeIcon> ADD TO CART
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.content}>
      <h5>{name}</h5>
      <div className={styles.stars}>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(i => (
          <a key={i} href='#'>
            {i <= stars ? (
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar}>{i} stars</FontAwesomeIcon>
            ) : (
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={farStar}>{i} stars</FontAwesomeIcon>
            )}
          </a>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.line}></div>
    <div className={styles.actions}>
      <div className={styles.outlines}>
        <Button variant='outline'>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart}>Favorite</FontAwesomeIcon>
        </Button>
        <Button variant='outline'>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExchangeAlt}>Add to compare</FontAwesomeIcon>
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.price}>
        <Button noHover variant='small'>
          $ {price}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far to implement this? I don't see anything at all regarding hover state, or conditionally rendering your buttons - there are a couple different approaches you could take, and it's usually best if you explain what you've attempted, and come here for help when you get stuck!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please follow the below code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function ShowButtonHover() {
    const [style, setStyle] = useState({display: 'none'});

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h2>Hidden Button in the box. Move mouse in the box</h2>
            <div style={{border: '1px solid gray', width: 300, height: 300, padding: 10, margin: 100}}
                 onMouseEnter={e => {
                     setStyle({display: 'block'});
                 }}
                 onMouseLeave={e => {
                     setStyle({display: 'none'})
                 }}
            >
                <button style={style}>Click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I did! Did that again, I hope you can see that now.

Comment: I clicked the arrow, however, as I understand you will not see that because I am new here with less than 15 points :( Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 11):

EDIT: made a codesandbox to make it easier https://codesandbox.io/s/stckovw-hideshow-hs3mh

A way to achieve this can be through these steps:

- Add `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` handlers to the component you want to trigger the rendering of the buttons, so ProductBox in your case
- Give the default class of your buttons a property of `display = none`
- Switch the display to block for example when the event handlers are triggered.

If you are keeping a stateless component for your implementation:

- `const [display, setDisplay]=useState('notdisplayed');`, with notdisplayed the default class with display=none
- `<div className={display}>` on the components you want to hide/show
- Call `setDisplay` in the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` definition